# How can I sequelize belongsToMany?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

How can I belongsToMany two different columns in the same table with the ID in a different table?

User Model

```
id: {
  primaryKey: true,
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
},
firstName: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(255)
}
```

Message Model

```
id: {
  primaryKey: true,
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
},
userId1: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID
},
userId2: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID
}
```

belongsTo

```
thisModel.belongsTo(userModel, {
  foreignKey: 'userId1',
  foreignKey: 'userId2' // How can add this one here
})
```

Comment: In Sequelize `belongsToMany` is about M:N relationship. Do you really wish to have it? Or your question is about `two` belongsTo (N:1( relationships from the same table to the other same table but using different foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your case is a message has a sender(userId1) and a receiver(userId2). Below code will work for this case:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
  },
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255)
  }
});
const Message = sequelize.define('message', {
  id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
  },
  text: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  userId1: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID
  },
  userId2: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID
  }
});

// define the association
User.hasMany(Message, {
  foreignKey: 'userId1',
  as: 'sender'
})

User.hasMany(Message, {
  foreignKey: 'userId2',
  as: 'receiver'
})

Message.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'userId1',
  as: 'sender'
});

Message.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'userId2',
  as: 'receiver'
});

// Example using the association
sequelize.sync({
    force: true
})
  .then(async () => {
    // create some users
      await User.bulkCreate([
          { firstName: 'user1'},
          { firstName: 'user2'}
      ])

      const users = await User.findAll()
      const [user1, user2] = users
      const message = await Message.create({
        text: 'hello'
      })
      await message.setSender(user1)
      await message.setReceiver(user2)
      console.log(message)
  })
```